# Why is there a discrepancy between the tags of a question in the review queue and outside of it?

Tags: support, feature-request, review-queues

I recently started to go through SO's Mount Doom, A.K.A. the Close Votes review queue. I filtered the queue to [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295242/get-the-list-of-child-controls-inside-a-groupbox). Reading through it, I noticed it is not related to Java and so I went to edit it to remove the tag. I then found that the tag is not present in the question and assumed someone beat me to the edit. To my surprise, I looked for an edit notification / history, but found none.

Here are the screenshots I took to show my case.

This one is from the review queue, showing the tag:
[image]

This one is from the regular question viewing page (as linked above):
[image]
Notice that there is no "Last edited by" notification.

The only chain of events I can think of to resolve this is the following:

1. The asker included the tag.
2. The question was flagged and put in the review queue with the tag.
3. The user edited the question quickly after posting it (I think there is a 5 minutes grace period in which all edits count towards the original question, but I'm not sure) and removed the tag.
4. The questions in the review queue do not get updated - they are left the way they first came in (for good reasons I imagine).

**Questions:**

1. Is this what happened? If not, the question in the title. ([support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support))
2. Can the queue at list be updated with changes that apply to filters so that we don't get to review these "ghost" question? ([feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a review-audit, and you have the queue filtered.

Because there was no fitting review-audit available, they just took an arbitrary one and added one of the tags you selected (in this case the only one, [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)).

Comment: That is very cheap! How am I supposed to evaluate questions in languages I'm not familiar with? Even if I choose "Edit" I can't really edit it because what I'm shown in the "test" is not even there.

Comment: If things don't add up at all, you know it's an audit. Your choice whether you skip or answer "the expected way", which would be obvious as you looked at the source.